# SweetAlert confirmation box not setting AngularJS scope variable

Tags: angularjs, cordova, sweetalert

I have a Cordova/Angular app I'm working on in Visual Studio 2015.
The pages for the app are all divs on the index.html and appear/disappear based on an ng-show for each div.
There is a back button that resets the current page view to false and the home page to true. This all works if I just move backwards and forwards between the pages.
However, one screen requires a confirmation box to ensure the user actually wants to go back. To make it look stylish I'm using SweetAlert to show the confirm/cancel buttons and a message.
The confirm button sets the $scope.home to true and the $scope.gameScreen to false, just as the standard back button does but it doesn't actually go back. The confirmation box disappears and a console log shows the function was called correctly but the ng-show part doesn't fire.

My divs are below as is the back button function:

```
<!-- GAME SECTION -->
<div id="gameScreen" class="screen" ng-show="gameScreen">
...
</div>

<!-- HOME SCREEN -->
<div id="homeScreen" class="screen" ng-show="homeScreen">
...
</div>

$scope.goBack = function () {
    if ($scope.gameScreen != true || ($scope.currentGuess == "" &&          playersTurn == true)) {
        console.log("returning home");
        $scope.homeScreen = true;
        $scope.gameScreen = false;
        $scope.optionsScreen = false;
        $scope.instructionsScreen = false;
        $scope.onlineRegistrationScreen = false;
        $scope.pages.homePage = true;
        $scope.pages.currentPage = "home";

        console.log("home page: " + $scope.pages.homePage);
        console.log("scope.currentPage: " + $scope.pages.currentPage);
        console.log("scope.gameScreen: " + $scope.gameScreen);

        $scope.difficulty = "";
    } else {
        // confirm going back from game screen
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?", 
            text: "This will end your current game and record it as a loss.",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true, 
            confirmButtonColor: "#382E1C",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes (Lose Game)",
            closeOnConfirm: true
        }, function () {
            console.log("Go Back confirmation clicked");
            $scope.confirmLoseGame();
        });
    }
}

$scope.confirmLoseGame = function () {
    console.log("confirm lose game");
    $scope.gameScreen = false;
    // $scope.pages.homePage = true;
    //$scope.pages.currentPage = "home";

    $scope.goBack();
}
```

I tried calling the function outside of the SweetAlert confirm to see if it made a difference but even made it loop back through the goBack function to see it it helped but the game screen never hides itself.

Anyway, the point is Angular isn't responding to the variable controlling the ng-show changing when the SweetAlert is used.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Whenever you do anything with scope outside angular context need to use `$apply()` so angular knows to run digest

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks, just remembered that myself. Appreciate the prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by charlietfl, $scope.apply() called inside the SweetAlert method fixed the issue.

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.homeScreen = true;
        $scope.gameScreen = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A practical example to display an alert and then do something using the $scope is as follows:

```
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function(){
      $scope.$apply(function () {
          console.log("make something");
          $scope.showSome = true;
          $scope.showAnother = false;

        });
    });
```

This worked for me...!